# Google Cloud Translation API got error "403 User Rate Limit Exceeded"

Tags: translation, translate

I'm using Google Cloud Translation Service for my bussiness 
When I use URL "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2" to translate my text. The result is :

```sh
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded",
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I already used payment version, and config all in Google Cloud Console but useless.
Who can help me...

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coqg1.png)

Comment: Did you tried to ask their support maybe the limit is exceeded as it's written in the response for the key that you wrote in the url as parameter ?

Comment: I already config in Google Cloud Console and sent email to them, but the answer was unclear...

Comment: Hello, did you figure out the problem and found a solution for this? If so, can you share please?